# crm 2011 solutions developed against different rollups

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

i have several CRM 2011 development images and a test, train and production environment. All environments are currently on rollup 4, assuming i apply rollup 7 to test, train and production are there any issues with the managed solutions i deploy being developed against rollup 4? Previously i have encountered issues where a developer has passed me a solution developed against rollup 2 but test, train and production were only on rollup 1 so would not install! but assuming production is always ahead or the same i am assuming there should be no issues?

regards
richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently opened a ticket regarding the same question.

There is no dependency on the rollups as long as you don't require elements that where introduced with a specific one. The solutions itself are independent from a rollup

> A managed solution can be used for any CRM organization, independent from the rollup level. If needed you can use the attribute “minimumversion” to request a minimum rollup level from solution side. This could be used to make sure your customer has a minimum rollup installed before importing your solution.

See also [Maintain Managed Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328109#BKMK_RequireMinimumVersion)

> By default each managed solution can be installed in any Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online organization. However, you can restrict installation of your solution so that it cannot be installed to an earlier version. For example, you may want to require that specific service packs are installed before your solution is installed.
>
> If you export your managed solution and extract the contents, you can edit the solution.xml file containing the solution manifest. The  root element contains a version and minimumversion attributes. The version attribute describes the version you are using to export your solution. The minimumversion attribute default value is “5.0.0.0”. Increase this value to specify the minimum version required to install your solution. After you have set this value, select all the extracted files for your managed solution, including the solution.xml file you edited, and create a compressed file. Distribute this managed solution to your customers.